# Create RSS feed for content type = news?

Tags: 7, feeds

I created a content type called news items in drupal 7.  How do I tell D7 to create an RSS feed of ONLY news items?

When I go to /rss.xml, it displays all content types, which is too much.  I only need news items.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create feeds.  Simply add a new display of type "Feed" and customize the view to contain only the content you want.  Be sure to choose a path for your feed so that it can be accessed.

To add a "Feed" display:

Go to your views administration and select the view you want to edit. Towards the top of the page you will see the "**Displays**" heading with an "+ Add" button.  Click that and select "Feed" (See image below).  You will then have a Feed display that is using the Default Display's settings.

[image]

Comment: I already have a view that pulls news, but I forgot to include an RSS feed.  How do I edit the view to include one now?  I don't see that option when editing

Comment: oh i see it now.  Afte ryou edit view, there's an "Add" button beside the "Page" underneath "Display" header.  Use it.

Comment: Yep, just made an edit describing how

Comment: Thanks, but can you tell how images can be handled here?, because i'm not able to get image field data in the rss feeds.